# Positioning the same confirm button for 3 different panel displaying situations

Tags: website-design, gui-design, buttons, collapsible-panels

I have two **panels** that are **hidden/showed** depending on the value of the "State to assign" **dropdown**. I've been doubting about placing the Confirm button:

- In a **fixed position**, for example: the bottom right corner (as in the last image).
- **Depending on each** displaying situation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

For now, as you can see, I've chosen the latter approach, cause I think:

1) It **follows the flow** when filling the inputs.
2) There's **just 1 button**, so it isn't a big deal (about "user orientation") to make the button "responsive".
3) Taking in count the case of the first image, where placing the button **fixed in the bottom right** would be quite unpleasant (**too much empty space in the middle**).

So, the questions:

1) Where would be better to place the confirm button in **both** approaches and which would you choose?
2) (maybe implicit in 1) )How could I improve my current approach (just referring to the positioning)?

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to make this form behavior vertical instead of horizontal. It's hard to know if this option is on the table - as I am not privy to the rest of the interface, but I think some of the problem stems from the horizontal growth of the form coupled with the confirm button under the textara.

And pertaining to older users, a vertical orientation would likely aide their traversal of the form, with the final resting place of their eyes and actions being the bottom. I have observed users of all ages struggled with actions that are out of alignment or "off-axis."

As always, prototyping solutions and testing your theories against userfeedback is best.
Hope this helps.